# Compare 43 variables in all possible ways

Tags: performance, loops, performance-testing, stata

I am trying to figure out which method is the best way to cross compare 43 variables (data sets, data)

I need to compare variable 1 with `variable 2,3,4,5,6,7....43` and then compare variable 2 with `variable 1,3,4,5,6,7....43` and so on, to variable no. 43.

I think i should use some kind of a loop, but i am clueless how to perform this operation efficient.

I think I just need some kind of pseudo code. Either way I want to do this in a do-file in Stata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming e.g. variables `var1-var43` and that the "comparison" between the first and the second differs from that between the second and the first, which is what your question implies, then

```
forval i = 1/43 { 
    forval j = 1/43 { 
        if `i' != `j' { 
              <code for comparison between var`i' and var`j'> 
        } 
    }
}
```

With other variable names, `foreach` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

As @NickCox suggested, you could use a O(NxN) nested loop. If that takes too long, which it could if your "43" is actually 1000, then there's a better way. Sort each list (indirectly), which is O(N logN), and run a merge-order loop, which is O(N), so altogether it is O(N logN).

Comment: How would this work if you need to calculate directly with every pair of variables, as could be planned here?